# NodeJS down alert?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, forever

I am starting on nodeJS and already have a script running with forever. Is there a possible way to get notified (email) when forever/node crashes? Running on Ubuntu 12.04.
Many thanks

Comment: There are many online services notifying you when a web site is down. That might be a simple solution.

Comment: not a website, just a service or a port

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using events of process object to handling notifications about app crashing or when its shut down.
You can read more about this [here](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html)

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
 //Notification code when application process is killed
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  //Notification code when application gets uncaught Exception
});
```

Comment: isn't it dangerous to run IO code like sending an email within an uncaughtException-handler block?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node domains http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html to catch exceptions and do something you need.
Email example:

```
var d = require('domain').create();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'userpass'
    }
});


d.on('error', function(er) {
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Fred Foo ✔ <foo@blurdybloop.com>', 
        to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', 
        subject: 'Crash',
        text: er, 
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {});

});
d.run(function() {


    // here all dangerous logic

});
```

Comment: Please don't just answer with a link. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer